# Create a view for A table with new columns JOIN(ed) on B table queries about the last maching records with certain parameters. How to simplify code?

Tags: mysql, join, view

I'm not sure if I can ask this question here. Let me know if I can't. Basically, my code works fine, but I would like to improve the code itself.

I'd like to improve this code to require fewer lines (faster is optional, but not mandatory). I think my code could be optimized in space because it performs two queries about the same table in the two `join` statements.

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48485ae14b03393d83817bc03af3e09f) of my query. Note that even when the page said "MySQL 8.0" **I'm using MySQL 5.7** (an old version where a lot of new stuff can't be done).

First, we create the (simplified) tables:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
 code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE transactions (
 date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 code varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 mode enum('Buy','Sell','Count','Return') NOT NULL,
 stock int(11) NOT NULL,
 average_price decimal(14,4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (date),
 KEY Code (code),
 CONSTRAINT transactions_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES products (code) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then we populate with records:

```
INSERT INTO products(code, name) VALUES
  ("A", "Alpha"),
  ("B", "Beta")
INSERT INTO transactions(date, code, mode, stock, average_price) VALUES
  ("2000-1-2", "A", "Buy", 5, 1),
  ("2000-1-3", "B", "Buy", 4, 2),
  ("2000-1-4", "B", "Sell", 2, 3),
  ("2000-1-5", "B", "Sell", 1, 4),
  ("2000-1-6", "A", "Buy", 6, 5),
  ("2000-1-7", "A", "Buy", 8, 6)
```

Finally, we make the view (if you prefer in your answer you can alter the table instead of making a view, but I didn't figure how):

```
Create VIEW products_view_joinA_and_JoinB
  AS select t1.code, t1.name, t2.stock, t2.average_price as cost_usd, t5.date as last_buy
    from (products t1 left join (
      select t3.stock, t3.code, t3.average_price from transactions t3
      where (t3.date = (
        select t4.date from transactions t4 where (t4.code = t3.code) order by t4.date desc limit 1)
      )) t2 on((t2.code = t1.code))
      left join(
        select t6.code, t6.date from transactions t6
        where (t6.date = (
          select t7.date from transactions t7 where (t7.code = t6.code and t7.mode = "Buy") order by t7.date desc limit 1)
       )) t5 on((t5.code = t1.code)))
```

Finally, we test it:

> ```
> SELECT code, name, stock, cost_usd, last_buy FROM products_view_joinA_and_JoinB
> ```
>
> ```
> code | name  | stock | cost_usd | last_buy           
> :--- | :---- | ----: | -------: | :------------------
> B    | Beta  |     1 |   4.0000 | 2000-01-03 00:00:00
> A    | Alpha |     8 |   6.0000 | 2000-01-07 00:00:00
> ```

For a better understanding I make these two views with half code each one:

> ```
> Create VIEW products_view_joinA
>   AS select t1.code, t1.name, t2.stock, t2.average_price as cost_usd
>     from (products t1 left join (
>       select t3.stock, t3.code, t3.average_price from transactions t3
>       where (t3.date = (
>         select t4.date from transactions t4 where (t4.code = t3.code) order by t4.date desc limit 1)
>       )) t2 on((t2.code = t1.code)))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT code, name, stock, cost_usd FROM products_view_joinA
> ```
>
> ```
> code | name  | stock | cost_usd
> :--- | :---- | ----: | -------:
> B    | Beta  |     1 |   4.0000
> A    | Alpha |     8 |   6.0000
> ```

And

> ```
> Create VIEW products_view_joinB
>   AS select t1.code, t1.name, t2.date as last_buy
>     from (products t1 left join (
>       select t3.code, t3.date from transactions t3
>       where (t3.date = (
>         select t4.date from transactions t4 where (t4.code = t3.code and t4.mode = "Buy") order by t4.date desc limit 1)
>       )) t2 on((t2.code = t1.code)))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT code, name, last_buy FROM products_view_joinB
> ```
>
> ```
> code | name  | last_buy           
> :--- | :---- | :------------------
> A    | Alpha | 2000-01-07 00:00:00
> B    | Beta  | 2000-01-03 00:00:00
> ```

The output works fine, but the code itself has some duplicated lines that I would like to remove, I think that would also increase its speed.

Answer (score 0):

(Getting rid of some redundant parens, plus wrapping and indenting:)

```
Create  VIEW products_view_joinA_and_JoinB AS 
select  t1.code, t1.name, t2.stock, t2.average_price as cost_usd,
        t5.date as last_buy
    from  (products t1
    left join  ( SELECT  t3.stock, t3.code, t3.average_price
                    from  transactions t3
                    where  t3.date = 
                          ( SELECT  t4.date
                                from  transactions t4
                                where  t4.code = t3.code
                                order by  t4.date desc
                                limit  1
                          )
               ) t2  on t2.code = t1.code
    left join  ( SELECT  t6.code, t6.date
                    from  transactions t6
                    where  t6.date = 
                          ( SELECT  t7.date
                                from  transactions t7
                                where  t7.code = t6.code
                                  and  t7.mode = "Buy" 
                                order by  t7.date desc
                                limit  1
                          )
               ) t5  on t5.code = t1.code
          )
```

`transactions` needs an index on `(code, date)`, but you effectively have such since InnoDB tacks the PK on the end of any secondary key.

Other indexes needed:

```
transactions:  INDEX(code, mode, -- in either order
                     date)  -- (for t7)
```

If you are using an old version of MySQL, `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is problematic since it would repeatedly execute the derived table (that subquery).  5.6 improves on it.  Ditto for having two `JOIN ( SELECT ... )` in a query.

Do you need `LEFT`?

`VIEWs` are syntactic sugar, and rarely (perhaps never) provide any performance.  Sometimes, they make performance worse.  So, experiment with the query outside a `VIEW`, then see if it still works as well in a `VIEW`.

If you are using MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.2), you could consider CTEs and use `WITH` to introduce the common code.

Other approaches to redundant code:

```
SELECT @var := ... FROM ...;  -- to compute a single value that is needed repeatedly.
```

or...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t  SELECT ...;  -- to build a table that you need to use twice.
```

Comment: And all that subselects (except the one with `LIMIT 1`) can be replaced by JOINs.

Comment: Sorry for the questions but: 1) I used `LEFT` because sometimes (rarely, but still possible), a product can be in `products` table but still not have any record in `transactions` yet. Without using `LEFT` that product would be invisible in the view. 2) I didn't understand about the keys... so should I use as primary key a combination of `Date, Code` or `Date, Code, Mode` ? 3) I use MySQL v5.7, would the `JOIN` repeatedly execute the derived table? 4) So, shouldn't I use a view? Have I (MySQL v5.7) have another option? Have I to use a temporary variable or table for that?

Comment: @EnderLook - I assume `date` is unique?  If so, leave the `PRIMARY KEY(date)` alone.  Add `INDEX(code, mode, date)` _or_ `INDEX(mode, code, date)`.

Comment: @EnderLook - 5.6 and later (including 5.7) will _probably_ evaluate t3 and t6 once and go to the effort to build suitable indexes for them.